# Potential Scipy bug in scipy.stats.mstats.theilslopes?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, bug-reporting

I'm a pretty new python/scipy/numpy and started using it because of Scipy's built-in Theil-Sen estimator function and Python's friendly iterability. After comparing results from my python script to other Theil-Sen calculations, I think I've found two mistakes in the scipy.stats.mstats.theilslopes function. I'm hoping a more experienced programmer/statistician can corroborate my findings.

The mstats source (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L673) has (I think) two sections with mistakes. In the first section, both series must be made floats and there is no reason to mask part of the series. So I would revise this code from:

```
  y = ma.asarray(y).flatten()
  y[-1] = masked
  n = len(y)
  if x is None:
      x = ma.arange(len(y), dtype=float)
  else:
      x = ma.asarray(x).flatten()
```

...to:

```
  y = ma.asarray(y,dtype=float).flatten()

  n = len(y)
  if x is None:
      x = ma.arange(len(y), dtype=float)
  else:
      x = ma.asarray(x,dtype=float).flatten()
```

Second, there appears to be a fundamental error in the calculation of the Theil-Sen intercept (as defined here: http://books.google.com/books?id=lK9gHXwYnqgC&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false). The current code calculates the median for all x's and y's and then works from those values and the slope to get the intercept. See:

```
slopes = ma.hstack([(y[i+1:]-y[i])/(x[i+1:]-x[i]) for i in range(n-1)])
slopes.sort()
medslope = ma.median(slopes)
medinter = ma.median(y) - medslope*ma.median(x)
```

However, the correct approach would apply the slope to each coordinate pair and then calculate a median from those values. So, I think the correct code would be:

```
slopes = ma.hstack([(y[i+1:]-y[i])/(x[i+1:]-x[i]) for i in range(n-1)])
slopes.sort()
medslope = ma.median(slopes)
intercepts = ma.hstack([(y[i] - medslope*x[i]) for i in range(n)])
intercepts.sort()
medinter = ma.median(intercepts)
```

So -- all you whizzes out there, what do you think? Thanks!

Comment: There was some work done on this in April: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3574.  Take a look at the code in the scipy master branch on github. Specifically, scroll down to the definitions of `theilslopes` in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py and https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py.  If it still looks wrong, please create an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Warren. I appreciate the links. Despite the claim that there are disagreements about the intercept value, the current calculation can't be right and isn't backed up by any other calculation method that I've read. So I'll start an issue on github, as you suggest. Thanks again!

Comment: These not being floats is what caused our bug, I have reported it to their github, shocking how 9 years later this is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/EnvStats/versions/2.3.0/topics/kendallTrendTest) on the subject of calculating Theil-Sen slopes and there they use the same as SciPy.

> Conover (1980, p. 267) suggests the following estimator for the intercept:
>   [image]

So I guess SciPy method is fine.